# Xamarin.Forms App crash on android on serializing object using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin to send data to a private server. I serialize some data which is an array of states objects consisting of an ID (int) and DateTime.
When the code hits this method

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentStates);
```

The app crashes on the emulator with the following lines in the output window

```
09-14 10:46:52.677 D/Mono    ( 3313): Config attempting to parse: 
'System.Numerics.dll.config'.
09-14 10:46:52.677 D/Mono    ( 3313): Config attempting to parse: 
'/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Numerics/System.Numerics.config'.
09-14 10:46:52.677 D/Mono    ( 3313): Assembly Ref addref 
System.Runtime.Numerics[0x9930e520] -> System.Numerics[0x9930e4c0]: 2
09-14 10:46:52.677 D/Mono    ( 3313): Assembly Ref addref 
System.Numerics[0x9930e4c0] -> mscorlib[0xab19ce40]: 74
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Numerics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Numerics.dll [External]
09-14 10:46:52.715 D/Mono    ( 3313): Assembly Ref addref         
Newtonsoft.Json[0xab19dbc0] -> System.Reflection.Extensions[0xb402d800]: 6
09-14 10:46:52.747 F/        ( 3313): * Assertion at 
/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-
android/external/mono/mono/metadata/metadata.c:1062, condition `index < 
meta->heap_us.size' not met
09-14 10:46:52.747 F/libc    ( 3313): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in 
tid 3313 ()
```

I have the latest version of visual studio enterprise

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.3.4
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.3.4+26730.15
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02046

Installed Version: Enterprise

JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2017.2    Build 109.0.20170824.131346

Xamarin   4.6.3.4 (0841c2aaf)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android SDK   7.4.3.1 (18558b4)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   10.12.3.3 (8a39106)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

I am also using Android SDK 7.1.
I suspected this line describes the problem

```
09-14 10:46:52.747 F/        ( 3313): * Assertion at 
/Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-
android/external/mono/mono/metadata/metadata.c:1062, condition `index < 
meta->heap_us.size' not met
```

but I couldn't find any help on that

Please help as I have no idea why this is happening.

PS it used to work very well before but after upgrading nuget packages it worked well for a while then without any reason it kept crashing.

Comment: Have you tried to go back to an earlier Newtonsoft.Json version?

Comment: Yes - till  v 8.0.3 still the same problem

Comment: Could you share the code of the class you are trying to serialize and some sample content for the object that leads to this error?

Comment: Interesting - that error means the index of the string is outside the allocated heap of memory for Xamarin. I've never seen it though - I'm curious to know how this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this was a bug in Xamarin and after updating to the latest version everything is working fine now.

Comment: Im having exact same issue in lattest version of both