# SIGABRT thrown xamarin forms custom getter/setter in model c#

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin, mono

**

### Notice; 21-12-2018 - changed the name of the question to be in line with new instance of this problem. Information regarding this is at the bottom.

**

I have been struggling with this error for 3 weeks now, tried everything I could think of, even reinstalling visual studio 2017.

First a bit of backstory;

I'm developing an app in which sandwiches can be ordered and most of the important features are finished. The entire ordering process has been working for the past 4 months. A couple of weeks ago there was kind of a disaster week, a blown out fusebox which caused a power outage. This somehow broke the firewall and the whole company network went down. During the installation of the android studio (alongside visual studio/xamarin). A couple of days later an update of visual studio 2017 went awry and I did a complete reinstall and removed android studio. Then the errors started showing up.

Most of the app still works fine, you can log in, check baskets, browse categories etc. however; when a specific function is called in the REST implementation the app shuts down and the debugger shows a Fatal signal 6 SIGABRT -6 error.

> 12-07 12:57:29.409 F/        (20795): * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/mini/unwind.c:640, condition `cfa_reg != -1' not met
>
> 12-07 12:57:29.409 F/libc    (20795): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 20828 (Thread Pool Wor), pid 20795 (e.Appnamehere)

Code below:

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> GetAllWithId<T>(Guid id)
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    var uri = GetURI<T>();
    ObservableCollection<T> oc = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    try
    {
        var tmpUri = "";
        // IF statements to determine URI, if no ifs succeed let run and catch exception.. ps. can be changed for typeswitch
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Product)) { tmpUri = uri + "/incategory/" + id; }/*use category id inside*/
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Order)) { tmpUri = uri + "/fromuser/" + id; }/*use user id*/
        var client = GetNewClient();
        using (client)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.GetAsync(tmpUri);
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(content);             
                oc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<T>>(content);// <<<<<< SIGABRT THROWN HERE
                //* Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-9/xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/mini/unwind.c:640, condition `cfa_reg != -1' not met
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }

    return oc;
}
```

There is one implementation using generics used by all controllers. The methods `getURI` and `getNewClient` respectively do build the URI to the corresponding type and returning a client instance.

Since the start of development, the xamarin core and other packages have not been updated since this usually breaks stuff. The current versions of all packages are the same as when development began (i.e. when there were no errors). (list of packages and versions at the bottom).

The error performs on the last 2 versions of the newtonsoft.json packages (error started at v11.0.2, then i updated to v12.0.1, the error still occurs). The API data is retrieved from and works as intended and returns the data in the correct format. 
The debugger shows no stack trace but does say that the error usually is caused by native mono code or native code used by dependencies.

If anyone needs more info I'll be glad to provide it since I haven't been able to find anything on google on how to fix this.

The error also occurs on all emulators (ranging from 512mb to 2gb ram, varying heap sizes and varying renderers. I am unable to test with a physical device because the network is still in lockdown and somehow the device cannot connect)

[image: VersionInformation]

**Update; it's fixed (I think).** 20-12-2018

I explicitly build the objects on the API side and send them as an object of their corresponding type (i.e. Product, Order etc.) instead of var.

After deserializing, reserializing and repeating that once more, i ended up with a working but grossly inefficient solution.

Following that, I cut a couple of custom getters and setters on properties on the models. (This is by no means a designated cause of this issue, but it helped fix it. )

It still worked, I then tried to use the original line of code as displayed in the question, which worked.

Note, I did re-install visual studio twice..(once when updating from 15.9.2 to 15.9.3, and yesterday uninstalled it and installed it with the new update, 15.9.4).

This is done on an older branch which still has the original versions of all dependencies.

All in all, this error should not be caused by errors in unmatching deserialization objects. Such an error should be thrown as a Deserialization error or something alike, not throw a native mono unwind error.

(The line of code that causes this error is surrounded by two nested try-catch blocks..)

**Update.. it happened again** 21-12-2018

So the error disappeared yesterday. I hoped it was for good, but now it re-occurred. I narrowed it down to the product model. (since the original error occurred when loading products and when loading historic orders, which only shared the same API method, it had to be there, and it was too).

The same error is thrown, except now the historic orders still work, except the products do not. It happened when i added a custom getter and setter to my model. code below;

```
public Object ProductImage {
             get { return ProductImage; }
             set {

                try
                {
                    if (value.ToString().Contains("/api/DynamicImages/getimageonly/"))
                    {
                        string imreBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(Constants.ObjectToByteArray(value));
                        ProductImage = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imreBase64Data);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ProductImage = value;
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex) { ProductImage = value; }


            }
           //   get;set;//<-- when i use this instead no signal abort is thrown but the images wont load when they are retrieved as either a file or data from my own API. (images retrieved as link to external site still work, falling back to place holders still works too.)
        }
```

When I revert to a simple get;set; it works. Any takers?
Note; I updated the name of the question to be more specific for this new issue.

Comment: please be specific: don't say "the last 2 versions of x", mention those 2 versions explicitly

Comment: Are you using the latest version of VS and xamarin.forms? Please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214899/xamarin-forms-app-crash-on-android-on-serializing-object-using-newtonsoft-json

Comment: @knocte added it in my answer

Comment: @BillyLiu-MSFT VS 2017 latest(15.9.3) update now. (though the error started in 15.9.2). I checked the link, it throws the same Signal abort error but because of a different reason, the error in the link is caused by memory heap error it seems. Mine is a bit different. sadly.

Comment: so is there a version of JSON.Net that doesn't have the problem?

Comment: @knocte i was using 11.0.2 for the past months and all worked fine. stuff went sideways when android studio got installed to work on a java project. Dont know it is related but i suspect it is.. anyway, i read that it might be a json.net issue and a new version just got released so i decided to update. It didn't fix the error though. Im kinda at a loss. (ps. Android studio has since been deleted)

Comment: Once i have enough rep to do so i'll put a bounty on this cause it is seriously hampering development.

Comment: dude this is confusing, you say 11.0.2 didn't have the bug, but in your question you also say that both 11.0.2 and 12.x reproduce the bug... and then you talk about AndroidStudio which doesn't have anything to do with Xamarin or Mono at all

Comment: @knocte yes its confusing. i started development with 11.0.2 at first it didnt producre the bug. then AS got installed (which i believe has its own mono installation, and since it is an error thrown in mono unwind.c..) anyway the bug then occured in 11.0.2 so i decided to update to the latest version 12.x in the hope that it would fix the problem. but it didnt.

Comment: AndroidStudio doesn't have mono

Comment: there must be something else in your environment that caused it, I would format my OS and start again

Comment: @knocte that is not an option, restoring all the data would be too time-consuming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the root cause is non-stop recursive call.
such as: 
ProductImage = value -> it will trigger call setter again.
as a result, setter is called again and again.

in java, it will report stackoverflow error for such case.
however, in mono, it show such error message, which is not clear for debug.

the solution is:

```
private Object _productImage;
public Object ProductImage {
    get { return _productImage; }
    set {
    ... 
    _productImage = {some value};
    }
}
```

Comment: its quite obvious now you pointed it out haha, Il accept it for other people who have this error.